# Phoenix: Interpolate function in string in template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a link I want to show in a set of breadcrumbs (using Slime for markup).

```
= link(@project.name, to: project_path(@conn, :show, @project))
```

This renders fine. But I want to show it in context, with other links.

```
# by concatenation
= link("Projects > ", to: project_path(@conn, :index)) <> link(@project.name, to: project_path(@conn, :show, @project))

# or by interpolation
#{link("Projects", to: project_path(@conn, :index))} > #{link(@project.name, to: project_path(@conn, :show, @project))}
```

The desired output would look something like this:

[Projects >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) Project name

Neither of those techniques work, however. How can I add this link to this text?

Bonus points if you can explain why this doesn't work as above.

Comment: Why don't you put them in different lines? `= link(...)\n| >\n= link(...)`?

Comment: Interpolation offers a lot more control and clarity, I think, but I see your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it multi-line:

```
= link("Projects > ", to: project_path(@conn, :index))
= link(@project.name, to: project_path(@conn, :show, @project))
```

You still can put it in a single line:

`link` function returns tuple like this: `{:safe, "link_string"}`. If you want to use a link as a string, you need to pick second element from the tuple via Kernel.elem(tuple, 1).
[See what content_tag (which is used in `link()`) returns](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#content_tag/2).

Also you need to render any html tags with `raw()`.

This works:

```
= raw "#{Kernel.elem(link("Projects > ", to: project_path(@conn, :index)), 1)} #{Kernel.elem(link(@project.name, to: project_path(@conn, :show, @project)), 1)}"
```